# UITableViewCell width too narrow (in grouped style)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want a custom look for my `UITableView` with images for the header, footer and cells.  For that matter, I return a `UIImageView` for the header and footer of the table, and I also set a `UIImageView` as the `backgroundView` of the cells.

The problem is that image of the cells is narrower than the header/footer.  This seems to be the default behavior of the grouped style of `UITableView`.  I need a grouped style so that the header won't overlap with the cells when scrolling.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

sorry my poor english, i could understend you wrong. But if there was not mistake:
if you will not find "right" solution, you may try this:
(this is not the best way to do what you whant, but it is the only one I can offer)

all you need is make your table view with only ONE section, without header. Then, just make every "raw" wich must be header of anothe section with different parameters:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       return <number of all raws in all sections plus number of sections, to make some raws - sections>;
    }
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (int i = 0; i < (number of sections); i++) {
        if (indexPath.raw == i*(number of raws in section i)) return (heigth of header);
}
    return (heigth of raw);

    }

    //Configure cells:

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        for (int i = 0; i < (number of sections); i++) if (indexPath.raw == i*(number of raws in section i)) {
    //set properties to headers
    return cell;
    }

    //set properties to raws
    return cell;
    }
```